# SQL: "no such column" with WITH clause

Tags: sql, subquery

I'm learning SQL and I would like to know why I'm getting 'Error 1: could not prepare statement (1 no such column: avg_quantity)' when I try the following query on the
[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all)

```
WITH avg_quantity AS (SELECT AVG(OrderDetails.Quantity) 
                      FROM OrderDetails)
SELECT Products.ProductName, OrderDetails.Quantity
FROM OrderDetails
JOIN Products ON Products.ProductID = OrderDetails.ProductID
WHERE OrderDetails.Quantity > avg_quantity
```

But when I try this code here, everything works fine:

```
SELECT Products.ProductName, OrderDetails.Quantity
FROM OrderDetails
JOIN Products ON Products.ProductID = OrderDetails.ProductID
WHERE OrderDetails.Quantity > (SELECT AVG(OrderDetails.Quantity) 
                               FROM OrderDetails)
```

Comment: ` SELECT AVG(OrderDetails.Quantity)  as avg_quantity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need a select against the CTE:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT AVG(Quantity) AS avg_quantity
    FROM OrderDetails
)

SELECT p.ProductName, od.Quantity
FROM OrderDetails od
INNER JOIN Products p ON p.ProductID = od.ProductID
WHERE od.Quantity > (SELECT avg_quantity FROM cte);
```

Functionally speaking, a CTE behaves like inlined SQL code.  It is not something like a user defined variable which stores some value (although on some RDBMS, CTEs can be materialized).

Answer (score 1):

You can do just like Tim said.
Another solution would be to just add the new table (avg_quantity) to the query, for exemple on FROM like so:

```
WITH avg_quantity AS 
(
    SELECT AVG(OrderDetails.Quantity) AS avg
    FROM OrderDetails
)
SELECT Products.ProductName, OrderDetails.Quantity
FROM OrderDetails, avg_quantity
JOIN Products ON Products.ProductID = OrderDetails.ProductID
WHERE OrderDetails.Quantity > avg_quantity.avg
```